# A Full List of Deontic Paradoxes?

Tags: logic

Other than the list found in the [Stanford Encylopedia article on Deontic Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-deontic/#4), is anyone aware of a comprehensive list of deontic paradoxes (preferably inclusive of the contemporary paradoxes)?

Answer (score 3):

The cool thing about SEP is not just that it has nice summary articles, but is also generally has comprehensive bibliographies for those interested in learning more.  You should probably look through some of those. In particular, just scanning through some of them, there's Castañeda, "The Paradoxes of Deontic Logic: The Simplest Solution to All of Them in One Fell Swoop" (1981), which might sound promising. Also, I've heard very good things about Hilpinen's *Deontic Logic: Introductory and Systematic Readings* as an introduction to the subject, so it might contain some such list.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find much on what you want, but does this help:

http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mally-deontic/